# Github - Crontab - GPG

Tags: github, cron

I have a bash script which runs fine when running individually, but not as a crontab task.

The script commits and pushes.

The error I get from Crontab is:

```
fatal: GPG_TTY is not set; add \export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to your profile.

See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`
```

I have added export `GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to:

```
 ~\.profile 
 ~\.bashrc
```

I have set up logging directly from my script, which shows it as successful (although it never pushes).

At this point, not sure what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your shell script add as second line (assuming first one is with shebang):

```
source /path/to/your/home/.bashrc
```

This will "import" the variables from `.bashrc` and make them available in `cron`. By design `cron` run in very limited environment and do not care about `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc

Comment: Thanks, absolute legend. It's now working!