# redis-cli works perfectly when bash script is executed manually but gives a "command not found" error when run from crontab

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, redis, cron, amazon-linux-2

- I have an Amazon Linux 2 powered EC2 instance that runs user data script and installs redis-cli as part of it. This redis instance runs inside Elasticache and therefore requires TLS support

I am [following the documentation by Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption-enable.html) to install it like this inside my user data script

```
yum install -y openssl-devel gcc
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable || exit
make distclean
make redis-cli BUILD_TLS=yes
install -m 755 src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
cd ..
rm -rf redis-stable
rm redis-stable.tar.gz
```

I added a crontab for the user ec2-user from my user data script whose definition goes like this

```
crontab -u ec2-user - <<EOF
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * /home/ec2-user/utils/src/elasticache/backup-elasticache-to-s3.sh > /tmp/backup-elasticache-to-s3.log 2>&1
...
EOF
```

This script basically has a single redis-cli command inside that looks like follows

```
...
RESULTS=$(redis-cli -h "${REDIS_HOST}" -p "${REDIS_PORT}" --tls info all)
readonly RESULTS
...
```

The script works fine when I execute it manually inside my EC2 instance by calling

```
/home/ec2-user/utils/src/elasticache/backup-elasticache-to-s3.sh
```

but fails inside the crontab every single time with the following error

```
/home/ec2-user/utils/src/elasticache/backup-elasticache-to-s3.sh: line 99: redis-cli: command not found
```

Anyone knows how to get it working? Should I install inside /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin? Should I reference the full path inside my script?

Super appreciate if someone can help me identify the cause of failure. I verified that the crontab was running the script as ec2-user by running a simple "echo $(whoami)"

Comment: Cron jobs don't have the same `PATH`. In your case it does not contain the directory of the `redis-cli` command. Try a cronjob with just `printenv PATH > /tmp/foo` and check.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet i will run it now and check but in the meantime, lets say it doesnt have /usr/local/bin in its PATH , how will you make the cronjob have a certain path?

Comment: You can set the PATH in your script (`export PATH=.....`). This makes sense anyway, because your script is then independent from the PATH setting of the parent process. This is also an advantage, when the script is used interactively.

Comment: i ran echo $PATH manually and it gives me /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin should I just say export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin" ? @user1934428

Comment: would it be a bad idea to hardcode a path inside a bash script or can i somehow dynamically load it while running

Comment: And you can set in in your crontab file: `PATH=...:/usr/local/bin:...`. Do not use `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` because some implementations do not expand `$PATH`. Use absolute paths of all directories that are needed for your cron jobs.

Comment: @PirateApp: I was not questioning that the PATH is correct when you run it manually; I was talking about the PATH at the time cron runs your job.

Comment: guys that did the trick, i added the path fully hardcoded in the first line and now it runs without error, but isnt a crontab file only supposed to have cron definitions, is adding a path to it invalid syntax?

Comment: Just two question below your (with `cron` tag): https://stackoverflow.com/a/77197682/2908599

Comment: Can you please self-answer the question to prevent the answer being 'stuck' in the comments?